# Initialize Script on Startup

Tags: 12.10, boot, server, startup

Is it possible to initialize a script upon startup in Ubuntu (precisely, Ubuntu Server 12.10)? I need to initialize a script to let the network card work, and so far I couldn't find a way to do so (the initializing on startup part).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A preferred way to execute a script during boot is to create an [Upstart job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#job). Job [configuration file](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#job-configuration-file) might go to `/etc/init` ([system jobs](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#system-job)) or to `~/.init` ([user jobs](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#user-job)).

[Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) is an event-based replacement for the venerable System-V init introduced for the first time in Ubuntu 6.10.

You will find answers to basic questions [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/faq.html).

To get started go [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html).

Detailed documentation having zilion examples can be found [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/).

Answer (score 4):

To do that you must add your script to `/etc/init.d/fileName` and then type this

`sudo update-rc.d fileName defaults`.

Don't forget to make file executable using `chmod 755 fileName`

Sources:

- [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/155476/how-do-i-make-a-script-run-upon-startup-of-the-ubuntu-machine)
- [Debian-Administration](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian)

Comment: Thanks alot, really saved me on that one. Don't have to  impatiently wait for a few seconds and then initialize the script anymore.